# Has NoDirectAccessAttribute changed for .Net 6?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

This is a stupid question, but as I'm trying to stop a user to see restricted page in asp.net application, I found an attribute that, as I could see, It was very usefull

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;


[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
internal class NoDirectActionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer == null || 
            filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Host != filterContext.HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.Host)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new
                                    RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", area = "" }));
        }
    }
}
```

When I tried to applied it to my project, I had some "contain definition error".

[image]

As you can see, I have this error on `.UrlRefferer` and `.Url`

[image]

This is the only "Show Potentional Fixes" suggestions I have. I don't have a `using` or gramatical fix suggestion.

I'm very sorry if this is a stupid question.

Answer (score 0):

with this you solve it.

```
if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.GetTypedHeaders().Referer == null ||
                    filterContext.HttpContext.Request.GetTypedHeaders().Host.Host.ToString() != filterContext.HttpContext.Request.GetTypedHeaders().Referer.Host.ToString())
                {
                    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/");
                }
```